# Error Import Excel to Outlook Contacts

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, import, contacts

This is frustrating... I've done this **hundreds** of times with no problems, and suddenly I get an error. The environment:

- Windows 10
- Outlook 2007
- Foo.xls file of Excel 97-2003

The process:

- Outlook --> File --> Import and Export...
- Wizard dialog --> Import from another program or file --> Next
- Microsoft Excel 97-2003 --> Next
- [Browse to 'Foo.xls'] + [Allow duplicates to be created] --> Next
- Select destination folder = Contacts --> Next

At this point I now get a series of error messages, such as:

> "ODBC Excel Driver Login Failed"
>
> "Unexpected error from external database driver (1)."
>
> "Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Comment: Did you try [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)?

Comment: Tried the full repair+restart cycle... same error.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with this: https://community.dynamics.com/gp/b/dynamicsgp/archive/2017/10/19/integration-manager-quot-odbc-excel-driver-login-failed-unexpected-error-from-external-database-driver-1-quot   
Anyway I ended up working around the problem by using CSV instead of XLS.